# ¿Cómo utilizar los datos recogidos en una clase en otra?

Tags: java, android

La cosa es que tengo estas tres clases con las que *juego*:

**chatListResponsehandler.java**

```
public class chatListResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

    private Context context = null;

    public chatListResponseHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

        dataChatsUser usersChat= new dataChatsUser();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String bytesResponse = new String(bytes);

        chatListData listChat = gson.fromJson(bytesResponse, chatListData.class);
        String array[]=new String[listChat.getChats().size()];
        for (int x = 0; x < listChat.getChats().size(); x++) {

            String pepe = listChat.getChats().get(x).getUsers().get(1).getName();
            array[x]=pepe;
        }
        usersChat.setUsernames(array);

        Intent listChatAd = new Intent(this.context, listChatAdapter.class);
        this.context.startActivity(listChatAd);
    }
}
```

**listChatAdapter.java**

```
public class listChatAdapter extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "llega", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_chat_layout);

            dataChatsUser dataChatUs =new dataChatsUser();
            String[] array = dataChatUs.getUsernames();
    }
}
```

**dataChatsUser.java**

```
public class dataChatsUser {
        private String[] usernames;

        public void setUsernames(String[] usernames){
                this.usernames=usernames;
        }
        public String[] getUsernames(){
                return this.usernames;
        }
}
```

La cuestión es que recojo los datos que pido de modo *REST* a un servidor y de ahí voy al `onSuccess` del `chatListResponseHandler`, los datos de estos usuarios los recojo en un array, y se los paso a la clase `dataChatsUser` con la intención de guardarlos y que a la hora de que se guarden cambiar de `Activity` y recogerlos con un `getUsernames()` en el `chatListAdapter`. Pero todo el rato el valor me da `null`. ¿Por qué puede ser? ¿Se hace como lo estoy tratando de hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pero todo el rato el valor me da `null`. ¿Por qué puede ser?

En la clase `listChatAdapter.java` estas creando una nueva instancia, la cual no es a la que originalmente guardaste los valores, por esa razón no obtienes datos.

```
 dataChatsUser dataChatUs =new dataChatsUser();
 String[] array = dataChatUs.getUsernames();
```

Como opción puedes crear una variable publica `usersChat` en la clase `chatListResponseHandler`, en la cual guardas los valores pero esta variable podrá ser leída por otra clase y un método público para extraer este valor `getDataChatUs()`.

```
public class chatListResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

    private Context context = null;
    public dataChatsUser  usersChat;

    private Context context = null;

  public chatListResponseHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

       //dataChatsUser usersChat= new dataChatsUser();
        usersChat= new dataChatsUser();
        ...
        ...
      String pepe = usersChat.setUsernames(array);
       ...
   }

  public dataChatsUser getDataChatUs(){
      return usersChat;
  } 
}
```

De esta forma mediante el método `getDataChatUs()` podrías obtener los datos.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "llega", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_chat_layout);

            //dataChatsUser dataChatUs = new dataChatsUser();
            //String[] array = dataChatUs.getUsernames();
           String[] array = chatListResponseHandler.getDataChatUs();
    }
}
```

Comment: ahora el único problema que me aparece en la parte de chatListResponseHandler.getDataChatUs(); me aparece que "el método estático getDataChatUS no puede ser referenciado a un método estático.

Comment: ups! public static dataChatsUser getDataChatUs(){ @Zaldaiz